# Image Quality Distorted after convering Mat image to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

```cpp
void Qtexample::on_pushButton_clicked()
{ 
    QString img_path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Select your image", QDir::homePath());

    img = imread(img_path.toStdString().c_str());
    Size size(200, 200);
    cv::resize(img, img,size);
    cvtColor(img, img, COLOR_RGB2BGR); //convering the image to RGB for QImage to handle well 

    QImage Qimg((uchar*)img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);  // converting Mat image to QImage
    ui.label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Qimg,Qt::AutoColor).scaled(ui.label->width(), ui.label->height()));  // displaying the image inside the QLabel with the help of QPixmap
    // imshow("image", img);  // show image
}
```

the code works by converting a Mat image to QImage but the resulted Image is distorted a little and I need help on it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the resize or the scaled pixmap that is distorting the image? I'm pretty sure that the problem is there not at the convertion

Comment: @Zlatomir the image quality is much better when I commented out the resize function and the scaled function too,  but I think the is more room for improvement ..

Comment: @lookatyouman Have you tried changing the interpolation used by OpenCV's resize? Something like `cv::resize(img, img, size, 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA)` See [the doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#resize) for more details.